# Android Studio Assets - Possible name restrictions?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, assets

Not all of my assets are being added to my APK. Many of them are being skipped.
I have Invalidated Caches, rebuilt project, restarted Android Studio, and also one-by-one manually created files and folders in the Android Studio project tree.

Here is my file asset structure, I have marked the missing files and folders:

[image: file structure]

I am wondering why I might be getting this issue. I have tried other solutions to this problem, as mentioned above, but these marked files are *never* making it into the APK no matter what. Why might this be, and how can I solve it?

Comment: You can't use blank character , `-`  for resources name.

Comment: `bigfont-orig.png` and all assets in `Hello 3D/` make it into the APK just fine

Comment: Oww.. I was wrong, didn't see that you're using assets folder. 

I think that problems is the subfolder are more than 4. Try moving the marked files to another subfolder not more than 4.

Comment: There is a 4-subfolder restriction?

Comment: Probably, I haven't use more than 4 subfolder in my project.

Comment: Hmm. Moving them down a directory did work. Is there some way I can get around this? I need my asset files to be organized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170555/discussion-between-treyten-carey-and---).